Can I configure how many messages a @KafkaListener can receive?
We are using Kafka to receive, process and send messages.
We noticed that we receive 2-3 messages at max and nothing beyond that.
The messages themselves could be from 500KB to around 20MB.
Is there a way to configure how many messages a single @KafkaListener receives when the function is invoked?
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafkalistener.topic}", batch = "true",concurrency = "1")
public void listen(List<ConsumerRecord<?,String>> records,Acknowledgment ack) {
//records.size() is 3 at maximum
}


Are you looking for the property: spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.records=10

@LokeshGupta it is already set to 500.
